# Powershell ImportExcel module disabling autofiltering and other formatting

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using PowerShell 5 to create Excel worksheets using the excellent ImportExcel module but I'm finding that the worksheet created has auto-filtering enabled and the first row and alternate rows have a blue background colour.  This even occurs with the simplest example:

```
$data = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Region,State,Units,Price
West,Texas,927,923.71
North,Tennessee,466,770.67
East,Florida,520,458.68
East,Maine,828,661.24
West,Virginia,465,053.58
North,Missouri,436,235.67
South,Kansas,214,992.47
North,North Dakota,789,640.72
South,Delaware,712,508.55
'@

$data | Export-Excel
```

[image]

How do I stop the worksheet being created with the autofiltering and row background colours?

Comment: If you actually use a path then it shouldn't happen. If you want to open an in memory excel you can add `-TableStyle None`

Comment: You might find support at https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon that did the trick as far as the row colouring is concerned.